# ViewPager in a Fragment in an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a Navigation Drawer Activity `(NavActivity.java)`, which has a fragment `(HomeFrag)` with a recyclerView. When a user selects an item from the recyclerView, it replaces the current fragment with this one (`itemFrag` which contains a ViewPager). This ViewPager does not appear at all!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">


        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/nivSplash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/nivIcon"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@mipmap/splash_land"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nivIcon"
                android:background="#AA000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nivIcon"
                android:background="#AA000000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRole"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/nivIcon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nivIcon"
                android:background="#AA000000"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryTransparent"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

itemFrag.java:

```
onCreateView() {
    contentView = Inflater.inflate...;
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) contentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
...
...
SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

Comment: You only need to show the layout and code of the Fragment if that is what your question is about.

Comment: Sorry @cricket_007 , I didn't get what you're trying to say

Comment: This XML look more like an Activity since it contains an `AppBarLayout`. This is your Fragment layout? If so, then is there data in the ViewPager adapter? Basically, I was trying to say, please show a [mcve].

Comment: No, this is the code in a Fragment (ItemFrag). I want a collapsing View on top of the ViewPager (which is in a fragment called HomeFragment). I took out as much code as I could and I've a feeling the mistake is in the xml .. which is why I didn't post much from the .java

Comment: Oh, this is from your previous question. Okay. Umm, I think the `android:layout_height="192dp"` is causing you to have some "left over" piece of the toolbar when it is collapsed.

Comment: Or you need `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` on the CollapsingToolbar

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried setting the height to "1dp" and there's a black layout (maybe a bar?)  that appears there instead (about 40dp high). changing the scrollFlags didn't work either..

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you are facing? It is the collapsing or the ViewPager? Are you able to see the ViewPager content if you temporarily remove the CollapsingToolbar?

Comment: Well in this question, I asked "the ViewPager doesn't appear", but you decided to answer my 3rd question from my previous post lol :P

Comment: The ViewPager doesn't appear even without the collapsingToolbar

Comment: But it does appear if i only remove the NestedScrollView, but I cannot scroll down

Comment: You have a horitzontal ViewPager as your only element of the Fragment body. Why do you need a NestedScrollView?

Comment: This is my first time using a NestedScrollView. Maybe I am mistaken. The fragments in the ViewPager will have a long list of items (vertical)

Comment: ViewPager is a horizontal view. The documentation says "Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data"

Comment: Yes, I know :) but inside one of those Fragments, I need a vertical list (scrollable).

Comment: Then the inner View/Fragment layout manager will be responsible for that, not the Fragment with the ViewPager

Comment: You're right. But if I put the scrollView in the inner fragment, I cannot get the CollapsingTooldbar to collapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for the NestedScrollView. You should only need that if there is vertically scrollable content to be displayed under the collapsing toolbar.

Since you only seem to have a ViewPager, then try this

```
...
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryTransparent"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<!-- end of layout -->
```

Comment: Awsome! This worked lol, but the only issue i am having now is that when I scroll the innerFrag, the CollapsingToolbar doesn't scroll

Comment: here's my xml for both: OuterFrag: http://pastebin.com/MDgNQz6F ... innerFrag: http://pastebin.com/AigWxpeF

Comment: It only collapses if I scroll up while my finger is on the CollapsingToolbar

Comment: I replaced the ScrollView with a NestedScrollView and it now does what I wanted it to do, but there's still that small 40dp line that shows on top

Comment: I haven't used the collapsing toolbar enough to know what would cause it not to fully collapse